# XPath query for attributes containing a namespace prefix

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I am trying to query an XML document using XML::XPath in Perl, but I am having issues when the attribute name of an element contains a namespace prefix.

Sample XML:

```
<root xmlns="root-ns" xmlns:cat="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="A" schematron-version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="some location">
  <elementA id="elementA">
    <ElementA-1>
      <ElementA-1-1 id="ElementA-1-1" xlink:href="#ElementA-1-1">
        <cat:catalog>
          <cat:uri name="name" uri="#something"/>
        </cat:catalog>
      </ElementA-1-1>
    </ElementA-1>
  </elementA>
</root>
```

My find query looks like the following:

```
if ($nodeset = $nodes->find("/root/elementA[\@id='elementA']/ElementA-1/ElementA-1-1[\@xlink:href='#ElementA-1-1']/cat:catalog/cat:uri/\@uri") {
  print "nodeset found.\n";
}
else {
  print "no nodeset found.\n";
}
```

When I run this against the sample XML document, XPath complains about the ':' in @xlink:href attribute name, but I have not been able to find the correct way to reference this attribute in my query.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Perl code in your question doesn't compile because the parentheses are mismatched.

If I fix that problem and swap single and double quotes (so that nothing needs to be escaped) then your XPath expression works fine as it is.

Note that you have a very specific XPath string, and it is rarely necessary to be quite so explicit about the contents of the path to the node you're interested in. Just `//cat:uri/@uri` would do the job here.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::XPath;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new(xml => <<'END');
<root xmlns="root-ns" xmlns:cat="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="A" schematron-version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="some location">
  <elementA id="elementA">
    <ElementA-1>
      <ElementA-1-1 id="ElementA-1-1" xlink:href="#ElementA-1-1">
        <cat:catalog>
          <cat:uri name="name" uri="#something"/>
        </cat:catalog>
      </ElementA-1-1>
    </ElementA-1>
  </elementA>
</root>
END


my $nodeset = $xp->find('/root/elementA[@id="elementA"]/ElementA-1/ElementA-1-1[@xlink:href="#ElementA-1-1"]/cat:catalog/cat:uri/@uri');

for my $node ($nodeset->get_nodelist) {
  printf "Name:  %s\n",  $node->getName;
  printf "Value: %s\n",  $node->getValue;
}
```

**output**

```
Name:  uri
Value: #something
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, which helped to show me that I wasn't crazy and my actual code should have worked eventhough I fudged writing the sample above.  I found my problem.  I was using the wrong element name from my actual content.